# Fancybox aling isn´t work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox to show a iframe when a page load, but, the vertical aligment in Firefox and Chrome doesn't show fine, and IE work perfect. The code is this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $.fancybox.open([
                {
                type : 'iframe',
                href : 'http://www.example.org/online/index.html',
                title : 'Inscribete',
                width: 800,
                height: 580


                }
], {
    padding : 0
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the *iframe* with those dimensions, then you may need to use `fitToView` set to `false`.

Also, check your syntax. I would rather do something like

```
$.fancybox.open({
    type: 'iframe',
    href: 'http://www.example.org/online/index.html',
    title: 'Inscribete',
    width: 800,
    height: 580,
    fitToView: false,
    padding: 0
});
```

That should work fine in most of modern browsers.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o6gwLw7m/)**

Comment: The size of the windows works fine, but iframe show at bottom of the page on firefox or chrome, IE works fine, show at the center of the page.

Comment: @IngGermanOchoa most likely are your CSS setting for the html or body tags creating the issue (check positioning or size of those elements)